# Amazon MWS Order API timestamp must follow ISO8601

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using Amazon MWS order API (ListOrders) and I can successfully run it on Amazon Scratchpad but I am getting the following error

> Sender
>   MalformedInput
>   timestamp must follow ISO8601

Below is the php script which I got from some Stackoverflow post

```
$base_url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01";
$method = "POST";
$host = "mws.amazonservices.com";
$uri = "/Orders/2013-09-01";

$params = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId' => "AWSAccessKeyId",
    'Action' => "ListOrders",
    'SellerId' => "SellerId",
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'SignatureVersion' => "2",
    //'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time()),
    'Version'=> "2013-09-01",
    'MarketplaceId' => "MarketplaceId",
    'CreatedAfter'=>'2014-07-06T19%3A00%3A00Z',
    'CreatedBefore'=>'2014-07-08T19%3A00%3A00Z'
    );

// Sort the URL parameters
$url_parts = array();
foreach(array_keys($params) as $key)
    $url_parts[] = $key . "=" . str_replace('%7E', '~', rawurlencode($params[$key]));

sort($url_parts);

// Construct the string to sign
$url_string = implode("&", $url_parts);
$string_to_sign = "GET\nmws.amazonservices.com\n/Orders/2013-09-01\n" . $url_string;

// Sign the request
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $string_to_sign, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, TRUE);

// Base64 encode the signature and make it URL safe
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));

$url = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/Orders/2013-09-01" . '?' . $url_string . "&Signature=" . $signature;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
$response = curl_exec($ch);

$parsed_xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
print '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

Can anyone help find my mistake?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are sending three date values:

```
'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z", time()),
'CreatedAfter'=>'2014-07-06T19%3A00%3A00Z',
'CreatedBefore'=>'2014-07-08T19%3A00%3A00Z'
```

For a start, you can get rid of the second parameter to `gmdate()` since it defaults to `time()` anyways. Other than that it's fine and should not be the cause of your problem.

The other two parameters have url encoded characters (the colon is encoded as `%3A`) which you then send through `rawurlencode()` to encode once more. That will replace the percent sign of above encoing with `%25`. The `CreatedAfter` value you are actually sending to Amazon for `CreatedAfter` is therefore `2014-07-06T19%253A00%253A00Z`. Try this instead:

```
'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"),
'CreatedAfter'=>'2014-07-06T19:00:00Z',
'CreatedBefore'=>'2014-07-08T19:00:00Z'
```

Comment: One more thing I have to change MarketplaceId to MarketplaceId.Id.1 otherwise it was giving me the error **Unexpected list element termination**

Answer (score 1):

I too had the same issue with the java api .i fixed mine by sending the timestamp in following format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss'Z'".